# A question concerning the pointwise convergence and continuity of the shift function.

Tags: real-analysis

For any $a \in \Bbb{R}$, let $f_a : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be the shift function defined by $f_a (x) = x−a$. Show that $f$ is continuous if and only if, whenever a sequence of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ converges to zero, $f_{a_{n}}$ converges pointwise to $f$.

[I'm stuck on this  problem, therefore a full solution is appreciated]

Comment: You didn't give the correct definition of $f_a$. (As stated what you say cannot possibly be true, since $f_a$ simply has nothing to do with $f$.)

Comment: What is the function $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$|f_{a_n}(x) - f(x)| = |(x-a_n)-x|=|a_n|. $$
So if $f_{a_n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow f$, then $a_n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0$, and conversely.

Comment: Why do you think $f(x)=x$? You might also note that what you prove is not what the question asked. (In fact the statement of the question was very confused...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Your statement in parentheses answers your question :)